# :target pseudo class doesn't find target

Tags: html, css

I want to change the style of an element im my html with the :target pseudo class.
My markup
(first one is a button, second is the target element):

```
<a id="btn01" href="#theTarget"><span class="adtb-orange"><span>Call to action</span></span></a>

<div id="theTarget" class="col-lg-6">target</div>
```

the css:

```
#btn01:target {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

This doesn't work and i have no idea why. Can anyone help me with that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your css class by :

```
#theTarget:target {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: That's not how i understood :target so far. But interestingly, it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`:target` doesn't work like that. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3atarget):

> The `:target` pseudo-class represents the unique element, if any, with
>   an id matching the fragment identifier of the URI of the document.

In short, you should have only one `:target` rule in your CSS, which will automatically be applied when an anchor is clicked:

```
:target { outline: solid red }  /* draw a red, solid line around the target element */
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/7wr8z/)

Comment: let's assume i have two buttons: First points to target1 and 2nd points to target2 and let us further assume that i want to change target1s color to red and target2s color to green if the corresponding button is clicked. Is this possible by using only CSS?

Comment: No, not using CSS alone.